# Yummly API returns strange characters in JSON response (Android)

Tags: java, android, json, httpresponse, http-get

I access the Yummly database for recipes in my Android app using the html query:

```
http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=MY-APP-ID_app_key=MY-APP-KEY&q=KEYWORD
```

Even though their documentation states that the GET requests are returned in the UTF-8 format, I find some strange characters in the code, like: `Pots de Creme a l&rsquo;Orange`.

The problem is not only limited to my Android application, but the same is shown in the Chrome browser. Funnily enough, when I tried opening it in Internet Explorer, it appeared to be ok: `Pots de Creme a l’Orange`, but there were other things like `crĂ¨me fraĂ®che`, which in Chrome appears sometimes as `Cr&egrave;me Fra&icirc;che` and sometimes correctly as `Crème Fraîche`.

What is the difference between the browsers that makes them interpret the response in different ways?
And, more importantly, what can be done in Android/Java to eliminate this issue? Do you have any ideas?

In Android I use HttpGet to fetch the data from server and then I pass it to a JSONObject.

Comment: Did you make sure the String variable storing the response is also UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: I didn't really precise that, however I followed one of the advice on StackOverflow and put `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content, "UTF-8"));`. On the other hand the problem exists also in web browsers so I don't think that the Java code can do anything about it because I the issue exists probably earlier on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for Yummly. There was an inconsistency in the way we handle these things, but it should be fixed now.

By way of explanation, the &; syntax is SGML/XML/HTML entities which are used to escape certain characters. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for example. For users of most browsers, whether the document contains a & or &amp; makes not difference and so we weren't thorough enough in normalizing them. But for an app such as yours, obviously it does make a difference and we've added a more thorough normalization. Everything you get from the API should not be UTF8 without any HTML entities.

Just for reference, [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) has a handy Java utility for this type of thing

Comment: Thanks, the problem seems to be solved, and now everything looks nice in my app :)